# spring security 3 authentication method

Tags: security, spring, authentication

I'm new at Spring Security. I've read the docs and I have two questions, in order to integrate it in my webapp:

(1) I use Hibernate. Is it better to config the authentication customizing the authentication provider by implementing the UserDetailsService, accessing the Dao?

Or is it better to config it with a JDBC-user-service referencing the database connection and specifying the querys on the user and user_roles tables?

I think using Hibernate Dao is more difficult, but it would be a more database independent solution, isn't it?

(2) In either of both cases above (Hibernate vs JDBC), do I have to implement in the presentation layer the methods to login and logout? Or Spring Security framework dooes it automatically for me? I know I can use the UserDetails to know the info about the current user logged in, in order to use it in the views, for example to show or not the links for login/logout depending on wether the user is logged in or not. But what about the methods?

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I understand, implementing the UserDetailsService is more for user customization . If you can get the data by a straightforward query, use JDBC-user-service .
2. You do not need to implement the methods . Spring will take care of login and logout depending on your configuration. For clogoff ,you could wrap the link with 'j_spring_security_logout'

   ```
   <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">
   ```

Check the [form-login](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) element for more info . A sample is as below.

```
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" 
                always-use-default-target="true" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
```